# How to instanciate python list on javascript side ? Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

i would like to create a list on my python script that could be accessible on the javascript side.

```
button = Button()
list = []

def update_list():
    list.append(1)

button.on_click(update_list)

button.js_on_click(CustomJS(args = dict(list = list), code = """
console.log(list);"""))
```

list is updated on python-side but stay empty when calling a CustomJS function.

Comment: Plain python objects, are just that—plain. They have no ability to auto-sync between Python and JS. Only Bokeh properties are automaticaly synced. The simplest way to do that with recent versions of Bokeh is by creating a `DataModel` subclass, with a property like `List(Float)`, etc. You can see an example here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.0/examples/plotting/data_models.py

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have found some interesting info on this link https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/advanced/extensions.html

Comment: Yes, I wrote that page, it's a good source of high-level information about the Python<-->JS interface in Bokeh and how models are mirrored across that interface. A `DataModel` is a way to create a simple kind of custom extension (one that only has property fields to mirror, but  no other "behaviour") without having to write the JS implementation yourself.